# How to turn the file-created-time into an integer?

Tags: rust

With fs::Metadata::created, I can get the created time of the file.

To compare between files in seconds, not milliseconds or whatever, the simple way is to turn the created time into an integer measured in seconds...

But how?

Comment: @synts   In Windows,if the directory’s been copied, created time of all the files would be changed to same time,but not actually the same time — ordering with fs::Metadata::created(), you’d got an unordered list.

Comment: To correct, “ in system-ordered ordering”

Comment: In Windows,it often renames automatically files as: f, f(1), f(2),f(3)...   —If I delete f(2), it would insert another f(2)— What a disaster!

Comment: So ,at first, I should check for secs, make sure the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You can directly compare instances of `std::time::SystemTime` that you get from `std::fs::Metadata::created()`, but I assume your use case specifically requires second-precision comparisons. In that case:

`SystemTime` itself does not offer unit conversion methods, but it does offer `duration_since()` and the constant `UNIX_EPOCH`. From [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html#associatedconstant.UNIX_EPOCH):

> ```rust
> pub const UNIX_EPOCH: SystemTime
> ```
>
> An anchor in time which can be used to create new `SystemTime` instances or learn about where in time a `SystemTime` lies.
>
> This constant is defined to be "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" on all systems with respect to the system clock.

Once you provide this kind of point of reference to `duration_since()`, and obtain a `Duration`, you can use `Duration`'s unit conversion methods to get the integers that you need. Example:

```rust
let a = someFileMetadata.created().expect("Creation time unsupported");
let b = someOtherFileMetadata.created().expect("Creation time unsupported");

let a_secs = a.duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH)
              .expect("File A thinks it was created before Epoch")
              .as_secs();
let b_secs = b.duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH)
              .expect("File B thinks it was created before Epoch")
              .as_secs();

if a_secs > b_secs {
    println!("File A was created later than file B!");
}
```